# why does my init.d script seem seem to run as if set -e was run?

Tags: bash, centos, scripting, sysvinit

I'm looking at an init.d script written by a previous coworker which is not functioning correctly now.  It's running on centos-6

After some experimentation I found the cause of the issue.  He wrote the script to wait up to 30 seconds for a kill -TERM command to runciton before reporting an error.  To do this he is running the command:

```
kill -0 $pid
```

to test if the killed program has died yet.

The kill -0 command is throwing an error:

```
/etc/init.d/celerybeat line 211: kill (<pid>) - No such process
```

it then exists immediately after this line fails.

This is what I would expect with set -e, but the script does not run set -e.  In fact it has the line commented out with a comment saying that the kill -0 command will fail if it's set, so he was very aware he didn't want it set.

This happens rather I run it via service or run the script direclty from the /etc/init.d directory

So..why is the script running as if set -e is set?  and more importantly, how do I prevent it from running that way, or rewrite the line to check if the pid is running without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the "exit on error" with `set +e` or `set +o errexit`, or run the command in a conditional so the error exit doesn't apply. Simplest would be:

```
somecmd ... || true
```

But that would destroy the return value, and you probably need it as `kill -0` doesn't do much except set it. So maybe something like this:

```
if kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null ; then
    echo it lives
fi
```

As for the "why", I think CentOS 6 runs Upstart, and at least [some Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) seems to state that Upstart runs scripts with `set -e` enabled.

Comment: By pure chance I was looking into CentOS upstart the other day and from what I could tell centos 7 runs it, but not centos 6.

Comment: @dsollen, what I can find (i.e. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart)) says that RHEL/CentOS 6 uses upstart, and RHEL/CentOS 7 uses systemd. But of course you know your system best.